# Update Dom once per Frame with setState in React

Tags: javascript, performance, reactjs

I have a `mousemove` event in `componentDidMount` and I want to call `setState()` only once per frame in order to update the DOM.
How to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what you mean with "once per frame", but I can imagine that you do not want to re-render on each pixel mouse-move.

What you could do is save timestamp and/or mouseposition in state, and only setState if more than x time, or more than x pixels of mouse-move have taken place. Something like this:

```
onMouseMove(mouseX, mouseY) {
  // check if more than 1 second has elapsed or if mouse has moved more than 10 pixels
  let timestamp = Date.now()
  if (
    (timestamp - this.state.now > 1000) ||
    (Math.abs(mouseX - this.state.mouseX) > 10) ||
    (Math.abs(mouseY - this.state.mouseY) > 10) {
    // store the new timestamp + mouse position in state, which will trigger re-render
    this.setState({
      now: timestamp,
      mouseX: mouseX,
      mouseY: mouseY
    })
  }
}
```